# Regular Expression for numericals

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

Hi People I am very new at Regex. I found out that 0-99 has expression "(?:\b|-)([1-9]{1,2}[0]?|99)\b" and 100-200 has "[1-2]\d\d".

I wanted to find out how it would be to write a range 9990001 - 9999991.

Any answer which makes it work would be gladly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `if (i >= 9990001 && i <= 9999991) { ... }`

Comment: that unfortunately will not work in the tool i use..I need the regex format

Comment: @ThomasMoors that's right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
999[0-9]{2}([0-8][0-9]|91|90)
```

999  **litteral**

[0-9]{2} **2 numbers**

([0-8][0-9]|90|91) **0 to 8  with any number or 91 or 90**

[Test it yourself](https://regex101.com/r/D5AY0f/2)

p.s. I agree with [@ikleschenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5449818/ikleschenkov) That you should just use an if stament with that range when possible. Regex is not the best (and not even fastest) tool for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options with 0X (X more than 0) , 1-8X and 9X (X up to 1):

```
999[0-9][0-9][0][1-9]|999[0-9][0-9][1-8][0-9]|999[0-9][0-9][9][0-1]
```